# How can i uninstall phpstorm from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04. i wanna uninstall phpstrom completely from my system. i tried couple of way but none are working.

```
sudo rm -rf .WebIde100/
sudo rm -R ~/.PhpStorm*
```

i tried both and few other ways but phpstrom still available in my system.
so how can i completely remove it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The method of uninstall of a program is dictated by how it was installed. You should reverse the installation process; so your use of `rm` to remove it implies you installed it via `cp` (or ran a script that `cp`'d the files to those locations).  If installed via `dpkg` or `apt` tools, you use the tools to remove them.   How did you install it?

Comment: i actually dont know.its actually my office pc. the last employee just install it.  @guiverc

Comment: Looking at the directories (using `stat`, `ls -l`) you can see when it was installed from date, then I'd look in `history` for commands executed around then to see if clues exist.  You've probably deleted the directories now (thus clue is gone), and by default date/times of command logs aren't kept; but being a corporate machine I'd hope they have better security than default). I don't know PhpStorm, but I'd try `whereis` to find where traces you believe to be there are still present, through to `fgrep` searches. You've not said why you see it which is itself a clue for where to look first

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
sudo snap remove phpstorm
```

Comment: Hi kibsi7. Welcome to the site! The question hasn't specified how it was installed. What if it was via apt? Also, perhaps you could include in your answer why your suggestion might work? (ie what it does)

Comment: Well , I had same issue yesterday  , I've tried exactly same commands but they didn't work so once I've written snap --help some options appeared then I wrote sudo snap remove phpstorm and  It worked!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little bit late to supply an answer, but I also had this issue on my Ubuntu installation recently.
It seems as if the PhpStorm set some identification marks in the local directory of the current user. Here is how you fix it:

1. Switch to your home directory using `cd ~/`
2. Remove any data related to PhpStorm using this:

```
 rm -rf .config/JetBrains/*
 rm -rf .cache/JetBrains/*
```

That's all. Now you should be able run your new evaluation mode.

Comment: thanks buddy it saved my time

Answer (score 1):

By using this command you removed only the config and license folders.
The application usually is installed in /opt/PhpStorm-*version*. Delete the folder, remove /usr/local/bin/pstorm (symlink)

Comment: bro this ans already been posted and that did not work see the conversation before u answer

Comment: i don't see a coment to tell him to delete /opt/PhpStorm-version and  /usr/local/bin/pstorm symlink. btw i cleared my installation today (kubuntu 18.04). Second part was clarification only

Answer (score 0):

for me after migrate from bionic (18.04) to focal (20.04), I remove :

```bsh
# soft
sudo rm -rf /opt/PhpStorm-*/
# launcher script which contains soft and config paths !
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pstorm
# config
rm -rf ~/.PhpStorm*/
# launcher
rm ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop
```